# Prevent docking AvalonDock

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

Is it possible to prevent docking one anchorable element to another one by using some filtering? For example, at viewmodel I can include some property `doctype`. For one anchorable element the value for `doctype` will be "a" and for the another one "b". How can I use property `doctype` to prevent docking if anchorable element with value "a" can't docking to anchorable element with `doctype` "b"? Maybe, there are other solutions for this.

Comment: How should the docking system react if no docking is possible?

Comment: Thanks for the question. I guess, should check `doctype` at draggable or docking event. I don't know how this works at AvalonDock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `IOverlayWindowHost.GetDropAreas` method at LayoutAnchorableFloatingWindowControl.cs

First step was intializing the type of content.

```
var floatingWindowContentHost = Content as FloatingWindowContentHost;
if (floatingWindowContentHost == null) return _dropAreas;
var rootVisual = floatingWindowContentHost.RootVisual;
Type type = null;

var layoutAnchorableFloatingWindow = draggingWindow.Model as LayoutAnchorableFloatingWindow;
if (layoutAnchorableFloatingWindow != null)
{
    //big part of code for getting type
    var layoutAnchorablePane = layoutAnchorableFloatingWindow.SinglePane as LayoutAnchorablePane;

    if (layoutAnchorablePane != null
        && (layoutAnchorableFloatingWindow.IsSinglePane
        && layoutAnchorablePane.SelectedContent != null))
    {
        var layoutAnchorable = ((LayoutAnchorablePane)layoutAnchorableFloatingWindow.SinglePane).SelectedContent as LayoutAnchorable;
        if (layoutAnchorable != null)
            type = layoutAnchorable.Content;
    }
    else
    {
        var pane = GetLayoutAnchorablePane(layoutAnchorableFloatingWindow.RootPanel);
        if (pane == null || pane.SelectedContent == null) 
            return null;

        var layoutAnchorable = pane.SelectedContent as LayoutAnchorable;
        if (layoutAnchorable != null)
            type = layoutAnchorable.Content;
    }
}
```

After this I just compare two types and put needed into `_dropAreas`.

```
foreach (var areaHost in rootVisual.FindVisualChildren<LayoutAnchorablePaneControl>())
{
    Type areahostType = null;
    var layoutAnchorablePane = areaHost.Model as LayoutAnchorablePane;
    if (layoutAnchorablePane != null && layoutAnchorablePane.SelectedContent != null)
    {
        var layoutAnchorable = ((LayoutAnchorablePane)areaHost.Model).SelectedContent as LayoutAnchorable;
        if (layoutAnchorable != null)
            areahostType = layoutAnchorable.Content;
    }
    // prevent docking different documents
    if (type != null && areahostType != null && areahostType == type)
    {
        _dropAreas.Add(new DropArea<LayoutAnchorablePaneControl>( areaHost, DropAreaType.AnchorablePane));
    }
}
```

For the prevent docking into document area, need to make changes for the same method at DockingManager.cs

For the visual preventing of DropTargets need to change OverlayWindow.cs

Answer (score 1):

In AvalonDock 3.5 (since 3.2 I think) there is a `LayoutAnchorable` property `CanDockAsTabbedDocument` which can be set to false to prevent toolwindows from being docked into the `DocumentPane`. This works only for the context menu in [AvalonDock 3.8 and earlier](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/issues/1460) while the drag&drop behavior is still buggy.

But you can use this fix to get the expected drag&drop behavior for AvalonDock 3.5.
The code below extends the `IOverlayWindowHost.GetDropAreas` in `DockingManager.cs`

The Key to this solution is the `dockAsDocument` boolean variable. It guards the **foreach** loop that is responsible for inserting any items into the `DocumentsPane` of the `MainWindow`.

The `dockAsDocument` variable is set to false as soon as there is one `LayoutAnchorable` (toolwindow) that can be found inside the `LayoutFloatingWindowControl` and was configured with `CanDockAsTabbedDocument="False"`.

```
IEnumerable<IDropArea> IOverlayWindowHost.GetDropAreas( LayoutFloatingWindowControl draggingWindow )
{
  if( _areas != null )
    return _areas;

  bool isDraggingDocuments = draggingWindow.Model is LayoutDocumentFloatingWindow;

  _areas = new List<IDropArea>();

  if( !isDraggingDocuments )
  {
    _areas.Add( new DropArea<DockingManager>(
        this,
        DropAreaType.DockingManager ) );

    foreach( var areaHost in this.FindVisualChildren<LayoutAnchorablePaneControl>() )
    {
      if( areaHost.Model.Descendents().Any() )
      {
        _areas.Add( new DropArea<LayoutAnchorablePaneControl>(
            areaHost,
            DropAreaType.AnchorablePane ) );
      }
    }
  }

  // Determine if floatingWindow is configured to dock as document or not
  bool dockAsDocument = true;
  if (isDraggingDocuments == false)
  {
    var toolWindow = draggingWindow.Model as LayoutAnchorableFloatingWindow;
    if (toolWindow != null)
    {
      foreach (var item in GetAnchorableInFloatingWindow(draggingWindow))
      {
        if (item.CanDockAsTabbedDocument == false)
        {
          dockAsDocument = false;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Dock only documents and tools in DocumentPane if configuration does allow that
  if (dockAsDocument == true)
  {
    foreach( var areaHost in this.FindVisualChildren<LayoutDocumentPaneControl>() )
    {
      _areas.Add( new DropArea<LayoutDocumentPaneControl>(
          areaHost,
          DropAreaType.DocumentPane ) );
    }
  }

  foreach( var areaHost in this.FindVisualChildren<LayoutDocumentPaneGroupControl>() )
  {
    var documentGroupModel = areaHost.Model as LayoutDocumentPaneGroup;
    if( documentGroupModel.Children.Where( c => c.IsVisible ).Count() == 0 )
    {
      _areas.Add( new DropArea<LayoutDocumentPaneGroupControl>(
          areaHost,
          DropAreaType.DocumentPaneGroup ) );
    }
  }

  return _areas;
}

/// <summary>
/// Finds all <see cref="LayoutAnchorable"/> objects (toolwindows) within a
/// <see cref="LayoutFloatingWindow"/> (if any) and return them.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="draggingWindow"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private IEnumerable<LayoutAnchorable> GetAnchorableInFloatingWindow(LayoutFloatingWindowControl draggingWindow)
{
  var layoutAnchorableFloatingWindow = draggingWindow.Model as LayoutAnchorableFloatingWindow;
  if (layoutAnchorableFloatingWindow != null)
  {
      //big part of code for getting type
      var layoutAnchorablePane = layoutAnchorableFloatingWindow.SinglePane as LayoutAnchorablePane;

      if (layoutAnchorablePane != null
          && (layoutAnchorableFloatingWindow.IsSinglePane
          && layoutAnchorablePane.SelectedContent != null))
      {
          var layoutAnchorable = ((LayoutAnchorablePane)layoutAnchorableFloatingWindow.SinglePane).SelectedContent as LayoutAnchorable;
          yield return layoutAnchorable;
      }
      else
      {
        foreach (var item in GetLayoutAnchorable(layoutAnchorableFloatingWindow.RootPanel))
        {
          yield return item;
        }
      }
  }
}

/// <summary>
/// Finds all <see cref="LayoutAnchorable"/> objects (toolwindows) within a
/// <see cref="LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup"/> (if any) and return them.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="layoutAnchPaneGroup"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
internal IEnumerable<LayoutAnchorable> GetLayoutAnchorable(LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup layoutAnchPaneGroup)
{
  if (layoutAnchPaneGroup != null)
  {
    foreach (var anchorable in layoutAnchPaneGroup.Descendents().OfType<LayoutAnchorable>())
    {
      yield return anchorable;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's correct to change `IOverlayWindowHost.GetDropAreas`, but the change seems a lot easier to me.

I simple removed this foreach in "LayoutAnchorableFloatingWindowControl.cs":

```
...
// Remove this foreach
foreach (var areaHost in rootVisual.FindVisualChildren<LayoutDocumentPaneControl>())
{
    _dropAreas.Add(new DropArea<LayoutDocumentPaneControl>(
        areaHost,
        DropAreaType.DocumentPane));
}

return _dropAreas;
```

and in the other implementation in "DockingManager.cs" you have to add an else cause:

```
if (!isDraggingDocuments)
{
    _areas.Add(new DropArea<DockingManager>(
        this,
        DropAreaType.DockingManager));

    foreach (var areaHost in this.FindVisualChildren<LayoutAnchorablePaneControl>())
    {
        if (areaHost.Model.Descendents().Any())
        {
            _areas.Add(new DropArea<LayoutAnchorablePaneControl>(
                areaHost,
                DropAreaType.AnchorablePane));
        }
    }
}
// -----> This else is new
else
{ 
    foreach (var areaHost in this.FindVisualChildren<LayoutDocumentPaneControl>())
    {
        _areas.Add(new DropArea<LayoutDocumentPaneControl>(
            areaHost,
            DropAreaType.DocumentPane));
    }

    foreach (var areaHost in this.FindVisualChildren<LayoutDocumentPaneGroupControl>())
    {
        var documentGroupModel = areaHost.Model as LayoutDocumentPaneGroup;
        if (documentGroupModel.Children.Where(c => c.IsVisible).Count() == 0)
        {
            _areas.Add(new DropArea<LayoutDocumentPaneGroupControl>(
                areaHost,
                DropAreaType.DocumentPaneGroup));
        }
    }
}

return _areas;
```

So, if you are not dragging an LayoutDocument, don't add the document pane controls to your drop areas.

Thats it - works for me.